# Creases at cutoff parts of normal map wrap

Tags: normals

If you look in this image of a head in texture paint mode

[image]

You can see a crease and change in shading.

Its also visible in the render

[image]

Can someone help me please :(

[image]

Comment: I don't believe that would be a problem when zoomed out, as it's hard to see already. :P

Comment: Yes but its there. I know its able to be dimished....

Comment: Just how would I fix it?

Comment: Try to fix it in sculpt mode, for an instane get a low strength F Smooth brush and go over it until it will be smoothed out

Comment: @Igor Tatarnikov I already tried. If anything it only reduced it slightly...

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of this place on the head in Edit Mode, because I think this may be caused by bad topology

Comment: I did just now Igor. It's in the post as of now.

Comment: How did you UV-unwrap it? What kind of textures did you use?

Comment: I unwrapped with smart uv project and normal map baked it with multires and the texture is 2048x2048

Comment: Also, an image of the topology is in the post now.

Comment: Ok...

When I set the coordinates to UV, it causes the crease. But I need it as a paint slot in texture paint mode, and this will only be in texture paint mode if its coordinates are set to UV.